# CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH does not work as expected

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, qt5

I'm compiling the same Qt/QML application on Windows, Linux, MacOS, WebAssembly, iOS, and Android.
So far, I found that detection of Qt's components only works on Windows, regardless whether I'm using it to compile a Windows version or cross-compiling to Android. It doesn't work neither on MacOS nor on Linux.

I tried pointing CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to Qt's installation prefix (~/Qt/5.15.0/wasm_32/), but it keeps on complaining about QtConfig.cmake. The only alternative I found to work was passing -DQt5_DIR for QtConfig.cmake to be found, but then it would keep on asking for at least 10 more .cmake files which I need to pass their paths one by one using _DIR variables. This way I would always end with a huge command and it's a major source of annoyance.

Note that I do not want to install Qt using apt or any other package manager. I only want to use Qt's installer since it gives me the flexibility of having multiple versions targeting multiple frameworks.

Is it a problem in Qt? CMake? Ubuntu?

Qt: 5.15.0

CMake: 3.18.0

Ubuntu: 20.04

Comment: "*then it would keep on asking for at least 10 more .cmake files which I need to pass their paths one by one*"... are these all Qt related paths, or other package dependencies? If they are different packages in different locations, this is, in general, how you tell CMake *where* to find them. What was the exact error message you were seeing in each case?

Comment: The only dependencies I have in this project are Qt's. All the errors look like this:

  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development....

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` should find the package configuration files (`.cmake`), assuming the *correct* path is provided. You can check the [search procedure](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) additional paths that are searched based on the path you provide `~/Qt/5.15.0/wasm_32/` as CMake tries to locate a config file. Note, you should use the *full* path, without the `~` shortcut. Where are the `.cmake` package configuration files located on your machine?

Comment: I did use fullpath. I just used the shortcut here. The full path of the config file is: /home/[username]/Qt/5.15.0/wasm_32/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake which follows the naming convention of <prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/

Answer (score 4):

Now I'm sure that I found it:
The toolchains had this:
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

It doesn't look like setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was enough. I had to do this also:
list(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "~/Qt/5.15.0/wasm_32")